# Erro ao criar fragment android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

estou fazendo um curso de android que possui navegação em barras e para isso é usado fragments, eu fiz do jeito do video porém as abas aparecem mas o conteudo dos fragments não, no console tenho esse erro:

RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

minha main activity ta assim:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_pagina);
//configurar adaptador
    TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);

    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

//xml 
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/vp_pagina"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Classe adapter

```
public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new ConversasFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ContatosFragment();
            break;
    }

    return fragment;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tituloAbas.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tituloAbas[position];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral) é utilizado de uma forma bem parecido com a sua, mas utilize essa sugestão que poderá lhe dar um ótimo resultado.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            ConversasFragment conversasFragment = new ConversasFragment();
            return conversasFragment;
        case 1:
            ContatosFragment contatosFragment = new ContatosFragment();
            return contatosFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}
```